# systemd script segfaulting when using systemctl

Tags: systemd

I have a startup script, that generates a segfaul when run under `systemctl`. I can't tell where, as journal and status just tell me it's exiting. `dmesg` tells me it generated a segfaults I can run this script just fine under `systemd-run` and it works perfectly.

I can't figure out how to tell where in the script my segfault comes from, as far as I can tell, it doesn't even invoke the `#!/bin/bash`. I would like to know:

1. What info from me would be useful to get help
2. How can I have this script invoked with `bash -x` or equivalent
3. Is there another tool besides `systemd-run` that would be useful?

Comment: What is the unit file? What is the script? What did you do when the error occurred?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to share the script (the conversation with legal would be time-consuming at best). Here is the unit file:

Comment: [Unit]
Description=FreeswitchServer Service
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/tmp/freeswitch.rc. start
ExecStop=/oomasw/service-5.0/freeswitch/freeswitch-354712/etc/rc.d/init.d/freeswitch.rc stop
StandardOutput=syslog+console
User=root
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitDATA=infinity
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitSIGPENDING=infinity
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitMSGQUEUE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
LimitLOCKS=infinity
LimitSTACK=240
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Comment: I ran the various systemctl status -l and journal commands, which just tells me it exited. dmesg shows a segfault. The script invoked by the unit file works just fine under systemd-run. I tried to instrument the script with echos, touching files in /tmp and syslog, and it never seems to output anything. I guess what I'm looking for are more techniques I can use to debug. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `Type=forking` instead of `Type=oneshot` – those `ExecStart=` and `ExecStop=` lines look like `freeswitch` is some kind of long-running service, and `Type=oneshot` isn’t appropriate for that.

Comment: That still crashes. I'm really trying to get it to spit out some debug output so I know what to look at. I can only get it to tell me that it's being killed and segfaulting, with no other info, and all techniques I know how to use do not cause it to crash...

Comment: The other thing I can do, which I really don't want to do, is construct the command line and call freeswitch directly. The startup script has a ton of logic in it, but I'm probably going to try it soon.

Comment: LimitSTACK=240 looks very small. `sysctl -a | grep core_` to look for where a core dump is generated and backtrace there after installing the debug info packages around the program that's segfaulting.

Comment: And bingo... systemd uses bytes for stack size. ulimit uses kbytes. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is that systemd uses bytes for stack size, an ulimit uses kbytes.

Comment: probably more to the point that 240 bytes is just too small :-)

Comment: @danblack It's not even possible to make the stack that small. Stack size is configured in increments of 4KB (at least on widely used architectures that's the case).